# Prolog Rule Squaring in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to modify this file to make the "square/2' Prolog rule work in haskell by taking two arguments "A, B". Both 
arguments are lists of numbers. The two list should have the same number of elements. It is true only if all elements B are the square of the elements from A and in the same order. The code below is the base case for the Prolog rule.

square([], []).

Comment: Can we see what you have tried with the Haskell version?

Comment: Well, you need to modify something. Do you actually have a question and need to know [ask]?

Comment: I count zero question marks in this post.

Comment: You have a lot of the elements of a good Haskell question, and even extremely introductory questions are on topic. But you don't have a question, so we don't know what to help you with. For example, you describe what the type of the function should be, can you write a type signature for it? If not, can you ask a question about the type signature? You have a base case in prolog. Can you write it in Haskell? If not, can you ask a question about the base case in Haskell? If you can do all that, can you ask a question about the next part of the problem?

Comment: Good point. That's what I get for being snarky.

Answer (score 1):

it can be written simply

```
isSquare [] [] = True
isSquare (x:xs) (y:ys) = x*x==y && isSquare xs ys
```

perhaps you may want to add lengths being equal too.

can also be written

```
and $ zipWith (\x y -> x*x==y)
```

or perhaps shortest

```
(==) . map (^2)
```